# Error executing a cmake project with Conan dependencies build via Clion's Docker integration

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, clion, conan

I'm trying to run a `cmake` project using `conan` as a package manager where the project is compiled in a docker container. I'm using Clion's docker integration support as outlined [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clion-toolchains-in-docker.html).

#### `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(FormatOutput CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_definitions("-std=c++11")

if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
    message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
    file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/0.18.1/conan.cmake"
            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake"
            TLS_VERIFY ON)
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

conan_cmake_configure(REQUIRES fmt/9.1.0
        GENERATORS cmake_find_package)

conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)

conan_cmake_install(PATH_OR_REFERENCE .
        BUILD missing
        REMOTE conancenter
        SETTINGS ${settings})

find_package(fmt)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main fmt::fmt)
```

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian:sid

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get update && apt-get -y install tzdata

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
      gcc \
      g++ \
      gdb \
      clang \
      make \
      ninja-build \
      cmake \
      autoconf \
      automake \
      libtool \
      valgrind \
      locales-all \
      dos2unix \
      rsync \
      tar \
      python3 \
      python3-dev \
      python3-pip \
  && apt-get clean

RUN pip install conan

ENV CONAN_USER_HOME=/.conan_docker
RUN mkdir $CONAN_USER_HOME && chmod 777 $CONAN_USER_HOME
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  clion-cpp-env:
    image: clion/debian/cpp-env:1.0
    build: .
    platform: linux/amd64
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    ports:
      - 2222:22
    volumes:
      - "/tmp/conan_docker:/.conan_docker"
    restart: on-failure
```

#### Clion Docker Toolchain Configuration

[image]

#### Build output

```
-- Conan: Using autogenerated Findfmt.cmake
-- Found fmt: 9.1.0 (found version "9.1.0") 
-- Library fmtd found /.conan_docker/.conan/data/fmt/9.1.0/_/_/package/0d8b943d676dc202f180a2598d04457e173d7b97/lib/libfmtd.a
-- Found: /.conan_docker/.conan/data/fmt/9.1.0/_/_/package/0d8b943d676dc202f180a2598d04457e173d7b97/lib/libfmtd.a
-- Library fmtd found /.conan_docker/.conan/data/fmt/9.1.0/_/_/package/0d8b943d676dc202f180a2598d04457e173d7b97/lib/libfmtd.a
-- Found: /.conan_docker/.conan/data/fmt/9.1.0/_/_/package/0d8b943d676dc202f180a2598d04457e173d7b97/lib/libfmtd.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/docker_conan/cmake-build-debug-docker
[Finished]
```

#### Output on trying to run executable

```
====================[ Build | main | Debug-Docker ]=============================
/usr/bin/cmake --build /tmp/docker_conan/cmake-build-debug-docker --target main -j 6
ninja: error: '/.conan_docker/.conan/data/fmt/9.1.0/_/_/package/0d8b943d676dc202f180a2598d04457e173d7b97/lib/libfmtd.a', needed by 'main', missing and no known rule to make it
```

###### While the local compilation builds and runs without complaints, on compiling with the **Docker toolchain on Clion**, I'm able to build but *not* run the executable. Apparently the library is not found where `conan` installed it previously. How do I make this work?

Comment: My guess would be you need to mount the Conan folder from your host machine as the configure and build are being done in separate docker instances and the Conan data is being lost

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alan Birtles suggestion, the flaw in my approach was that the volumes/mount information was missing from my container instance.

Although I'd mentioned it in my `docker-compose.yml` file, it's likely that Clion is not running the docker container via `docker-compose`, and instead using the `docker run` command internally instead.

Thus, one needs to append to one's Docker `Container Settings:` the following volume mount information:

```
-v /path/to/localmachine/conan-docker:/conan_docker
```